# can you help me about loop in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputt = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
        while (true) {
            
                System.out.println("'1' for Create a new Standard Room\n "
                    + "'2' for Display all room information\n"
                    + "'3' for Display the total number rooms\n"
                    + " '0' for exit.\n");
                int a = inputt.nextInt();
            
        
                if ( a == 1) {
                StandardRoom room = new StandardRoom();
                }
                
                if (a==2) {
                StandardRoom.displayInf();
                }
                
                if(a==3) {
                StandardRoom.displayCreatedroomnumber();
                }
                
                if(a==0);{
                System.exit(0);
                }
            }

    }

}
```

when i create a room, the menu is not coming again guys i need help.
I took the data from another classes.
first of all i push the 1. buttton then i create a room but i cant see any menu after i created a room
.............

Comment: We cannot reproduce your issue because we do not have the StandardRoom class. You also have typos such as "inputt" - this code won't run under any circumstances.

Comment: no no i have StandardRoom classes on my eclipse i just sent the main classes to here and there is no syntax error in my code. i just wanted to learn why while loop is not working.

Comment: "there is no syntax error in my code. "  - please explain inputt.nextInt();

Comment: i just wanted to say the program did not give error. i tried to take just 3 number which is (1,2,3) for  if statements, may be -probably- it is wrong. i did not wanted to challenge to you i am so sorry. i have just started to learn. i wanted to take input as a integer that is why i write nextInt. and i identify my scanner class as a "inputt" what should have i done ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an extra semi-colon ; after (a==0) which is causing the problem